# The favicon for the 2016 Winterbash page is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, favicon, winter-bash-2016

On the [2016 Winterbash page](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/) (which is currently a countdown), the http call to get the favicon currently reutrns the html for the page, rather than the icon itself.

[image]

And as such, we get an ugly default icon. Quick fix so we can really appreciate all the effort you guys and gals put in to make the page look great?

I'm using Chrome 54.0.2840.99 m on Windows 10.

Comment: strangely enough for me it only shows the ugly icon when on https. On http I somehow got a favicon before this went wrong. Now I must admit that I have this url on auto-reload since August 2016, it might be cached ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be OK now.

I've pushed a fix - I can see the icon in the browser tab now.

Comment: Right now I'm still getting the same results. I'll keep waiting to see if it's caching somewhere.

Comment: You are not getting the favicon to show up in the browser tab?

Comment: I'm not seeing it either. No [favicon.ico](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/favicon.ico) and no HTML meta tag for it.

Comment: I've got the snowflake image now in the browser tab. Navigating to `http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/favicon.ico` now properly redirects to `http://cdn-prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/favicon.ico` which serves the correct image, rather than an internal redirect to `/`.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara - no need for a meta tag. If it doesn't exist, most browsers will try to fetch `favicon.ico` from the root.

Comment: @Oded I know, I just wasn't sure if it was supposed to be at the root or on the CDN so I checked both. Loading now for me too.